# Excel - changing the pattern of the cell by clicking it

Tags: excel, events, vba

I would like to find some VBA code that when I left click in a cell on a sheet it will change the cell to yellow.  Then lets say I didn't want the cell yellow, I could right click and it would change back.  I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code that works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)    
   Call ChangeCellColor(Target, 6)       
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, _
                                       Cancel As Boolean)
   Call ChangeCellColor(Target, xlNone)      
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeCellColor(Target As Range, CLR As Integer)    
   Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = CLR      
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lance: Thanks that worked, is there a way to limit it to a certain range of cells?

Comment: You would next the call in an IF statement, IF NOT Intersect(Target, Range(_whatever_)) Is Nothing.

Comment: @Lance: I actually have six different ranges that the change cell format would pertain to. They are: B7:F11 - H7:L11 - N7:R11 - B16:F20 - H16:L20 - N16:R20 I'm not sure how to write this into the code.

Comment: @Mike: use Range("B7:F11,H7:L11,N7:R11,B16:F20,H16:L20,N16:R20")

Comment: @Tim Williams: Would I replace a line within the code with what you wrote? Lances code above is what I'm using. Thanks

Comment: @Mike, you could replace the Range(_whatever_) with Tim's range, or you could create a global range variable to handle it.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Sorry Lance, but I am new to vba and I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: @Mike, just replace the text 'Range(_whatever_)' with the Range that Tim gave you.

Answer (score 2):

here is the code that will change the pattern (this is a striped gray)

```
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlLightUp
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

when I dont know the VBA off the top of my head, I go to Excel, View, Macros, Record New Macro..

I then make the changes in Excel that I want, then I go back and turn off the Macro.  Lastly, I go and view the macro.. and bam! the code Im looking for is generated there for me.

Comment: Using "Record Macro" is an axcellent suggestion--but this answer is a great example of why you should treat it as a learning tool, and _almost_ never acutally use the recorded macro. The recorder sets all the properties it thinks make sense, whether or not they're changing. Your production code should only touch the properties that are being changed, plus any for which the value _matters_.